# Find the probability mass function of $Y=\min(X,c)$

Tags: probability, random-variables

Suppose that $X$ is a random variable with the geometric distribution. I want to find the probability mass function of $Y=\min(X,c)$ where $c$ is a real number.

I know that $X$ can be $0,1,...$
$$P(Y=y)=P(\min(X,c)=y)$$
$$f_X(x)=p(1-p)^{x}$$
And what happens when c is negative and $P(Y=c)$?
I'm really confused and I don't know what to do. Would someone give me a hint?

Comment: If $c\le 0$ then $P(Y=c)=1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\mathbb{P}(Y=y) =
\begin{cases}
p(1-p)^y,  & \text{if $y\in\{0,1,2,\dots,c-1\}$ } \\
\sum_{y=c}^{\infty}p(1-p)^y, & \text{if $y=c$}
\end{cases}$$

> And what happens when c is negative ?

When $c\le 0$ you have that $Y$ is a degenerate rv in $c$ that is $\mathbb{P}[Y=c]=1$

Answer (score 0):

Looks straightforward.

$f_Y(y)=f_X(y)$ for $y\lt c$.

$f_Y(c)=\sum\limits_{x\ge c}f_X(x)$.

Comment: Why for $y=c$ we have that?

Comment: What happens to $Y$ if $X \geq c$? For any value of $x$ where $x \geq c$, what's $P(X = x)$?

Comment: $f_Y(c) = P(Y = c) = P(\min(X, c) = c) = P(X \geq c) = \sum_{x \geq c} f_X(x)$